# Require has failed in php

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, I'm trying to require UserController.php from Controller.php but all I get is "HTTP ERROR 500" in browser. What's going on here?

Controller.php

```
class Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function call(){
        // echo 1;
        require_once "../Controllers/UserController.php";
    }
}
```

UserController.php

```
class UserController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    echo '111111111';
}

public function hi(){
    echo  '1';
}
}

$a = new UserController();
$a->hi();
```

Comment: You can't define a class inside a function definition.

Comment: You should have the `require_once` line outside the `class Controller`.

Answer (score 1):

Class definitions can't be nested inside functions or other classes. So you shouldn't have that `require_once` line inside a function definition. Move it outside the class.

```
require_once "../Controllers/UserController.php";

class Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function call(){
        // echo 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require_once "../Controllers/UserController.php";

class Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function call(){
        // echo 1;
        $a = new UserController();
        $a->hi();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.